# Avoid use of dll referenced from lib

Tags: c++, dll

I'm writing CPP unit test and the code of one used lib file references a procedure in dll.
I would like to remove this lib and the dll from the project.

I have made replacement methods for methods from the lib file, but there is one method which is imported from dll:

```
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) class CX * __cdecl CreateX(wchar_t const *)" (__imp_?....) referenced in function "...."
```

Is there a way how to declare a local function to link this with my code instead of dll import?

Comment: You will also have to change the .h file that the compiler uses so the linker will no longer look for a function that has the "I am imported from a DLL" attribute.  The __declspec(dllimport) attribute is an optimization, not a requirement.

Comment: Unless your providing a set of mock implementations for the functions and types provided by the library this is probably not going to work well.

Answer (score 0):

Just create a stub implementation of the missing file in your project. This will remove the linker error.